# Dictionary generation and data appending in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently I have data that looks like this (EDIT: this is an exmaple set, each time the script is run this data will change)

```
['G1R', '2.56']
['E219D', '11.56']
['L335D', '2.56']
['E248D', '90.28']
['E219D', '2.56']
['G1R', '15.78']
['L335D', '2.56']
```

What I want to do is automate the generation of a dictionary using the column containing mutation data e.g. 'G1R' as they key, then append the numeric data to that each time it occurs.

so basically an automated version of

```
r = dict();

r[ 'G1R' ] = []
r[ 'G1R' ].append(2.56)
r[ 'G1R' ].append(15.78)
```

The mutation column will change very frequently, hence needing to generate a new dict each time and there will be varying numeric entries that need appending for each key/mutation.

Any guidance on how to do this, or how to go about learning to do this would be appreciated.

For context, I am then going to run something like below, just to assess similarities and differences.

for k in r.keys():

```
print k

sum = 0
count = 0
for a in r[k]:

    sum += a
    count += 1
    print a

mean = sum/ count

passed = 0
failed = 0

for a in r[k]:
    if ( mean > a + 2  or mean < a - 2):
        failed += 1
    else:
        passed += 1

print "mean %.2f \n" % ( sum/ count)

print "passed: %d, failed: %d" % ( passed, failed)

if ( passed * 100 / (passed + failed) > 95):
    print "passed"
else:
    print "failed"
```

I'm very new to python/programming and learning solo, so if my question is badly worded/unclear apologies. Also if possible could I ask for explanation of solutions/recommendations to help with the learning process.

Comment: Are those lists at the beginning in any sort of list/dictionary?

Comment: Thats just data parsed and manipulated from multiple .csv files, using the standard python 2.7 csv reader module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect case for `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
initial_list = [
    ['G1R', '2.56'],
    ['E219D', '11.56'],
    ['L335D', '2.56'],
    ['E248D', '90.28'],
    ['E219D', '2.56'],
    ['G1R', '15.78'],
    ['L335D', '2.56'],
]
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in initial_list:
    d[k].append(v)  # possibly `int(v)` ?
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little? Also, does this account for the fact that the intial data will change every time the script is run?

Comment: @user3234810 -- defaultdict is a very well-known and documented dictionary subclass.  In this case, when the key (`k`) isn't found, the defaultdict calls `list` (which returns a new list), the new list is added to the dictionary associated with the key `k` and that new list gets returned.  If the key is found, it just does the normal thing.

Comment: Cool! bear with a newguy here. How can i automate the entry of the dataset each time? (to me, it looks like using this I would have to type out each set of results)